# Informing my main Activity of changes in power state from a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I'm building an Android kiosk app that will be running pretty much 24/7 for a small client job, playing video. However I've found out that at some points the power may go off meaning the tablet will need to stop running the app (or at least remove the screen keepalive) when the power goes out and re-set the settings all back up when the power comes back on so it doesn't completely kill the device. I've done a bit of Android work before but nothing like this. Given that I only have one activity, and the Activity will be running when I have the state received come to my onReceive call in my broadcast receiver (that I've registered in my Manifest file) what's the best practice/most idiomatic way for me to communicate that changed state to my Activity?

The current methods I've seen involve having a static reference to the activity be publicly available in the activity and using that to communicate with the activity (appropriately setting it as self or null depending on the App's lifecycle). Is that the most effective way?

Comment: Why don't you register the power in your activity?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to create `Observer/Observable` pattern, where your `BroadcastReceiver` implements an `Observable`, and notifies all interested parties about the changes. Activities (or other classes) interested in the power changes can register as an `Observer` and get called through their `update()` function when something happens.

Just don't forget to unregister from being `Observer` in `onPause()`, so your dead activities don't get called.

Answer (score 0):

@Hoan Nguyen is right. Your activity can register for battery events. Here's an example:

```
public class Test extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final TextView text = new TextView(this);
        setContentView(text);
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
                boolean charging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING || status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;
                text.setText(charging ? "Charging" : "On battery");
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    }
}
```

@lenik is probably also right that you should register/unregister in onResume()/onPause() rather than in onCreate(), but the above should get you started.